# Javascript nested while loop with continue statement not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, while-loop, continue

I'm trying to find all permutations of 3 arrays using nested while loops and the continue statement. It's almost working as I'd like, but is adding an extra element when control is given back to the outerloop. I'm going to rewrite it using recursion, but would like to know why it's doing this. Here's a link: http://jsbin.com/fuyup/15/edit

Thanks for any advice.

```
function findPermutations() {
    var g1 = ['a1', 'a2'],
        g2 = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
        g3 = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'];

    var g1p = 0,
        g2p = 0, 
        g3p = 0,
        g1len = g1.length,
        g2len = g2.length,
        g3len = g3.length, 
        temp = [],
        result = [];

    outerloop: while (g1p < g1len) {
        temp.push(g1[g1p]);

        while (g2p < g2len) {
            temp.push(g2[g2p]);

            while (g3p < g3len) {
                temp.push(g3[g3p]);
                result.push(temp);
                temp = [];  
                g3p++;
                continue outerloop;
            }

            g3p = 0;
            g2p++;
        }

        g2p = 0;
        g1p++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code has invalid syntax: `outerloop: while (g1p < g1len) { ...`

Comment: @hindmost `outerloop:` is a label. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Answer (score 0):

With that `continue` and the spare `temp = []` reset your control flow is really messed up.

Before `g3p = 0;` is executed and the innermost loop (that pushes to result and resets `temp`), the flow jumps back to `temp.push(g2[g2p]);` which is called twice on a the same `temp` array. I'm not going into detail here… If you need to know, use a debugger and step through the execution.

I've made a working version that uses `continue`, but I'm not really lucky with it:

```
outerloop: while (g1p < g1len) {
    temp.push(g1[g1p]);
    while (g2p < g2len) {
        temp.push(g2[g2p]);
        while (g3p < g3len) {
            temp.push(g3[g3p]);

            result.push(temp);

            temp = [];  
            g3p++;
            continue outerloop; 
        }
        g3p = 0;

        temp = [];
        g2p++;
        continue outerloop; 
    }
    g2p = 0;

    temp = [];
    g1p++;
    // continue outerloop; (implicit)
}
```

You can see the symmetric structure here, on every level the same things happen. And whenever we enter the `outerloop` to get the sequence

```
temp.push(g1[g1p]); temp.push(g2[g2p]); temp.push(g3[g3p]); result.push(temp);
```

executed, we reset `temp` before.

---

The usual idea to create permutations is to use no `continue`, but nest normal `for` loops that mutate an array, and take snapshots of each state to append to the result:

```
temp = [];
g1p = 0;
while (g1p < g1len) {
    temp[0] = g1[g1p];

    g2p = 0;
    while (g2p < g2len) {
        temp[1]= g2[g2p];

        g3p = 0;
        while (g3p < g3len) {
            temp[2] = g3[g3p];

            result.push(temp.slice());

            g3p++;
        }
        g2p++;
    }
    g1p++;
}
```